# Questions about enum

Tags: java, enums

If I have a Object

```
public class Genre {
    private int id;
    private int name;
}
```

And the id and name were been determined in advance, for example

```
if (id == 1)
    name = "action";
else if (id == 2)
    name = "horror";
```

My problem is how to create these two methods well

```
Genre.getName(1); // return "action";
Genre.getId("action"); // return 1;
```

I thought maybe I can use enum, like

```
public enum Genre {
    ACTION(1), HORROR(2);

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    private Genre(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = getName(id);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public static String getName(int i) {
        switch(i) {
        case 1 : return "action";
        case 2: return "horror";
        default :
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

But in this way, I have no idea how to

```
Genre.getId("action"); // return 1;
```

And im afraid i use enum not correctly.
Could you give me some advice? Thanks!
---
At first, What I want to do this is in my case i want to use id or name to find the name or id like

```
int id = 1;
Genre.getName(id); // return "action"
```

or

```
String name = "action";
Genre.getId(name); // return 1
```

And now thanks for all the advices, I realize why I want to do is

```
int id = 1;
Genre.getGenre(id); // return Genre that id = 1 and the name = "action"
```

or

```
String name = "action";
Genre.getGenre(name); // return Genre that id = 1 and the name = "action"
```

Comment: +1 for nice explaination with code as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using an enum for this, you can just use the existing enum facilities. The solution below assumes the enum name and ordinal may be used in place of your name and id fields:

```
public enum Genre {

    // ordinal 0, name = "ACTION"
    ACTION,

    // ordinal 1, name = "HORROR"
    HORROR;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int horrorOrdinal = 1;
    Genre horrorGenre = Genre.values()[horrorOrdinal];
    String horrorName = horrorGenre.name();

    String actionName = "ACTION";
    Genre actionGenre = Genre.valueOf(actionName);
    int actionOrdinal = actionGenre.ordinal();

    System.out.println(String.format("%s=%s %s=%s", horrorName, horrorOrdinal, actionName, actionOrdinal));
}
```

Output:

```
HORROR=1 ACTION=0
```

Another suitable way would be to use a map for the lookup, like Michał Šrajer suggested:

```
private static Map<Integer, String> genres = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    initGenres();

    int horrorOrdinal = 2;
    String horrorName = genres.get(horrorOrdinal);

    String actionName = "action";
    int actionOrdinal = getGenreIdByName(actionName);

    System.out.println(String.format("%s=%s %s=%s", horrorName, horrorOrdinal, actionName, actionOrdinal));
}

private static void initGenres() {
    genres.put(1, "action");
    genres.put(2, "horror");
}

private static int getGenreIdByName(String genreName) {
    for (Entry<Integer, String> entry : genres.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getValue().equals(genreName)) {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Genre not found: " + genreName);
}
```

Output:

```
horror=2 action=1
```

Design considerations:

In this example I chose to use the (fast) map lookup for id->name and wrote a seperate method (getGenreIdByName) to do the reverse lookup name->id. You could reverse that, or use a second map to make both lookups fast (at the cost of needing to maintain an extra map).

I chose to store the id and name in the map. You could also use the Genre class itself as the map value. This would allow you to easily add extra fields (like 'description') later on.

If you need to represent you genres in different languages, you can use ResourceBundles to localize the output. Create a language file in your classpath root.

In file genres_nl.properties:

```
horror=heel eng
action=actie
```

Where the _nl suffix in the filename indicates the language.

Then in your code, in initGenres:

```
ResourceBundle genreNames = ResourceBundle.getBundle("genres", new Locale("nl");
```

And when getting the genre name:

```
String horrorName = genreNames.getString(genres.get(horrorOrdinal));
```

Note that getString can throw the runtime exception MissingResourceException if the bundle is not found. To avoid this, make sure you create a 'default' bundle with no suffix (so in this case a file named 'genres.properties') which is automatically used in case no bundle for the used Locale can be found.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, and I need some time to consume!

Comment: `If you insist on using an enum for this...` - I'd prefer the enum version if the number of genres is fixed, i.e. might not be changed at runtime.

Comment: @Thomas I don't think that's the main criterium. I'd use an enum if you need to reference and distinct Genres a lot (i.e. you have Genre.ACTION etc. in your code a lot). If however this is used in a web application and the id/name are dynamicly passed to/from the frontend/persistence layer then I think a cached lookup like a map makes more sense. On top of that, data like a movie Genre is hardly every really unchanging in my experience. As a precaution I'd model it as a persistent entity to avoid having to redeploy my app for each change to Genre.

Answer (score 2):

Try the `valueOf(...)` method:

```
void String getId(String name) {
  //names are upper case, so account for that
  //handling non-existent names is an excersize for you
  valueOf(name.toUpperCase()).getId(); 
}
```

Note that there are better methods (like Thilo suggested), but if you have a string only, you might use that.

Edit: another note:

In your `getName(int i)` method, you might want to return `ACTION.name()` etc. in order to be more refactoring safe and use the correct case.

Comment: You are assuming the name field is somehow related to the enum name.

Comment: @Adriaan yes, at least it seems so from the posted source, esp. since the enum version doesn't have a name parameter for the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You can get its ID by calling Genre.ACTION.getId();

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
Genre.ACTION.getId()
```

And if you need to do it at run-time:

```
Genre.valueOf("ACTION").getId()
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I don't know the Genre at first. For example, I only get a String "action", how can I turn it into Genre.Action?

Comment: That is what `valueOf` does (you should make the name of the enum match that String, not having one uppercase and one lowercase)

Comment: So if the actual value I want is not "ACTION" but "ACTION" in some other languages like chinese, this way is not recommended?

Comment: In this case, you'd have to use some other mechanism. Maybe a lookup Map per language.

Answer (score 1):

```
ACTION(1, "action"), HORROR(2, "horror");
```

is a easy way to do it.
But if you are require to do it more often i would suggest you to create your own class and use `MAP<-"-,-"->` as micheal said.

Edit:----

As you said the rarely gonna change use this way-->

```
    public enum Genre {
    ACTION(0, "action"), HORROR(1, "horror"), ROMANCE(2, "romance"), COMEDY(5, "comedy");
    public final int id;
    public final String name;

    private Genre(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    };

    public final static int length = Genre.values().length;

    public static String[] getGenre() {
        String[] genreList = new String[length];
        int i = 0;

        for (Genre attribute : Genre.values()) {
            genreList[i++] = attribute.toString();
        }
        return genreList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Please remember use this as `Genre.HORROR.id`
also note that using this way is best as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean if I need to change the Genre often like adding or deleting genres. Then, I create Object for Action and Horror is better?

Comment: Yes, since enum should be prferred for constants. The values which will rarely change. for regular changing value why dont you prefer a class. Its all onto your requirement. Recently I was also on the same kind of problem, my name and id were constant and there were only few name as u have like HORROR, ACTION i used class but later i found a better way by doing it with enum. If they will rarely change go for enum. Tell me if any code required will edit my answer then.

Comment: I think in my case it is rarely change. But I still want to know how do this if it will be changed often. If I will change it often, how could I write it? Because if I create a Object Action, and give it id and name. How can I just use String "action" to get the Object Action? Thanks!

Comment: How can I just use String "action" to get the Object Action? what do you mean by this can you give an example. I didnt get it.

Comment: @cht- sorry there were some error in the code hence updated the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3166/discussion-between-amod0017-and-cht)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Enum Constructor with id and String:

```
public enum Genre {
    ACTION(1, "action"), HORROR(2, "horror");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public enum Genre {
    ACTION(1, "action"), HORROR(2, "horror");

    private final int id;
    private final String name;

    private Genre(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access particular element by it's name, you need to do it this way:

```
Genre.valueOf("ACTION").getId()
```

However, if you need to do it often, and in more dynamic way, I suggest to create regular class, and to keep all data in some `Map<String, Movie>` container.

Comment: Sorry for my JAVA and English. What you mean about "keep all data in Map<String, Movie>"?